# TDS mapping returns null for droplink

Tags: glass-mapper, tds

I have a rendering paramter template which has a droplink field. I have provided the datasource to this field and the datasource items selected will be of another template. We are using TDS and glass mapper. When I sync the item using sitecore I am getting GUID as type for the droplink. I am setting the custom data type in item properties as below,

**Type=Mytemplate** for the item.
And in TDS auto generated class it looks like ,

**Public virtual MyTemplate Mydroplink{get;set;}**

Now my problem is I am always getting null in Mydroplink for custom data type and without custom data type it is always {00000-00000-00000-0000}

We have similar field in other templates which are working fine and in TDS it is like

**Public virtual SampleTemplate Sampledroplink{get;set;}**

I am not sure what I am missing here. I am kind of stuck with this.

Comment: Could you please share your MyTemplate and SampleTemplate classes?

Comment: Both SampleTemplate and MyTemplate are same.   Public interface Setting{ string Value{get;set;} In my template it's Setting MyDroplink{get;set;}  in other template it's Setting SampleDroplink{get;set;}. Items of the droplink are of Settings class.  I want to access the Value property of the selected value. But Mydroplink is returned as null.

Comment: Can you share the complete class with attributes

Comment: That is the only field I have in that class. Im creating items based on this setting class and mapping them to the droplist field   of rendering parameter template.